# Is it possible to load a routerOutlet from a function in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I want to load a routerOutles in angular2 without a button, but can't figure out how to do it. This is how to do it with a button:

```
<button (click) = "load()" ><a routerLink="/next" routerLinkActive="active"> Load> </a></button
```

Now I just can't figure out how to set routerLink active in the function instead of the  tag.

my Attempt:

```
constructor(){{

load(){
 routerLink="/game";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" (click)="load()"></div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    constructor(private router: Router) {

        }

    load() {
            this.router.navigate(['/game']);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`navigate`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigate-anchor) method on the router.

```
 constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router.navigate(['game']);
    }
```

`routerLinkActive` Lets you add a CSS class to an element when the link's route becomes active.

Hope this helps!!